# How I should save the relational data in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

How I should save the relational data in mongoose?

Do I nest them?

For example, I have a schema to save restaurants. each user can feedback restaurant. and then I need to display the average rating of restaurant.
Do I nest all feed back in restaurant model or need to create a separate model for ratings?

what should be best approach respectively to mongoDb?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest to create an another model and use one-to-many relation for the same.

Comment: I suggest to creat one additional model for "Feedbacks/Reviews" and include the owner (User Model) and the restaurant (Restaurant Model) as reference. This way it's easy to get all reviews of one user or all reviews of one restaurant.

Comment: if you have a SQLSERVER relational database, you dont need migration to mongodb, you just need use sql server uper than 2016 and use Graph tables for this model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to start off by saying that **if your project is using relational data, I highly recommend that you use a relational database instead of MongoDb**. I love Mongodb as much as the next guy, and have done projects in Mongodb using relational data, but I've faced problems and I've seen and heard of too many projects that started off with Mongodb that had to go through a painful migration when the project got too big.

However, if you insist on using Mongodb, the following is what I would do:

**Disclaimer**: I have never used Mongoose so I'm just going to stick to the Mongodb schema and queries.

For the purpose of this answer, I mocked some JSON data from Mockeroo (https://mockaroo.com/).

Let's first invent some basic details for your **restaurant** collection schema (model).

```
{
  "_id": "Bujxd5U6k924D0M04NF2kOT6",
  "address": "Curabitur gravida nisi at nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam augue quam, sollicitudin vitae, consectetuer eget, rutrum at, lorem.",
  "name": "Stringtough"
},
{
  "_id": "EA50k3O5vxEi543z949L6u8M",
  "address": "Etiam vel augue. Vestibulum rutrum rutrum neque. Aenean auctor gravida sem.",
  "name": "Zontrax"
},
{
  "_id": "LOs7NI67ijwH1g26e38067G0",
  "address": "Proin eu mi. Nulla ac enim. In tempor, turpis nec euismod scelerisque, quam turpis adipiscing lorem, vitae mattis nibh ligula nec sem.",
  "name": "Holdlamis"
}
```

These are just the basic details that we'll need for our average rating query; you probably have a lot more details in your restaurants collection.

We can generate similar data for **users** where each user will have a _id, name, email etc, but that's not too important for the purpose of this answer.

Now let's get to the **reviews** collection.

When a user reviews a restaurant, it typically needs a short review paragraph and numeric rating. I would **not** be in favor of nesting all the reviews in an array, and like you mentioned in the question, would create a different collection to store all the reviews. So our "reviews" collection would look something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "0M63HJQ9MKXR538084U92Zt2",
  "restaurant_id": "EA50k3O5vxEi543z949L6u8M",
  "user_id": "s0j45hXpv4tgCAl5vD8a2b87",
  "rating": 4.8,
  "review": "Maecenas tristique, est et tempus semper, est quam pharetra magna, ac consequat metus sapien ut nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris viverra diam vitae quam. Suspendisse potenti.\n\nNullam porttitor lacus at turpis. Donec posuere metus vitae ipsum. Aliquam non mauris.",
  "date": "2019-06-03T06:36:19.000Z"
},
{
  "_id": "9K13616ouSn5H2o17l5Xp0x6",
  "restaurant_id": "LOs7NI67ijwH1g26e38067G0",
  "user_id": "RvYx1J1mU532iD3833286I7h",
  "rating": 2.3,
  "review": "Nulla ut erat id mauris vulputate elementum. Nullam varius. Nulla facilisi.",
  "date": "2019-09-10T06:31:43.000Z"
},
{
  "_id": "754233Q64d553XguY2Vi28a2",
  "restaurant_id": "EA50k3O5vxEi543z949L6u8M",
  "user_id": "s0j45hXpv4tgCAl5vD8a2b87",
  "rating": 4.7,
  "review": "Nulla ut erat id mauris vulputate elementum. Nullam varius. Nulla facilisi.\n\nCras non velit nec nisi vulputate nonummy. Maecenas tincidunt lacus at velit. Vivamus vel nulla eget eros elementum pellentesque.",
  "date": "2019-06-04T02:17:01.000Z"
}, //and so on...
```

Note that between the collections "users", "restaurants" and "reviews", the pairs users-reviews and restaurants-reviews would share one-to-many relationships. Therefore, each document in the reviews collection must have a restaurant_id and a user_id (preferably Mongodb ObjectIds), which would be the "foreign keys" (of sorts) for the other collections "restaurants" and "users". There will be only one of each such id, since only one user can write a particular review and that one review cannot be written for multiple restaurants. Then, of course we have the "review" field, which is what the user writes and the "rating", which is a floating point number, out of 5.

So, now say we have a page, where for each restaurant, we want to display the name, the number of reviews, and the average rating. How should we accomplish that?

I have written the following aggregation query for fetching the required data:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "reviews",
        "let": {
            restaurant_id: "$_id"
        },
        pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $eq: [
                            "$restaurant_id",
                            "$$restaurant_id"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: null,
                    "number_of_ratings": {
                        $sum: 1
                    },
                    "average_rating": {
                        $avg: "$rating"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "review_stats"
    }
},
{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$review_stats"
    }
},
{
    $unset: "review_stats._id"
}])
```

The result should look something like this:

```
[{
    "_id": "Bujxd5U6k924D0M04NF2kOT6",
    "address": "Curabitur gravida nisi at nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam augue quam, sollicitudin vitae, consectetuer eget, rutrum at, lorem.",
    "name": "Stringtough",
    "review_stats":
    {
        "average_rating": 3.1285714285714286,
        "number_of_ratings": 7
    }
},
{
    "_id": "EA50k3O5vxEi543z949L6u8M",
    "address": "Etiam vel augue. Vestibulum rutrum rutrum neque. Aenean auctor gravida sem.",
    "name": "Zontrax",
    "review_stats":
    {
        "average_rating": 4,
        "number_of_ratings": 4
    }
},
{
    "_id": "LOs7NI67ijwH1g26e38067G0",
    "address": "Proin eu mi. Nulla ac enim. In tempor, turpis nec euismod scelerisque, quam turpis adipiscing lorem, vitae mattis nibh ligula nec sem.",
    "name": "Holdlamis",
    "review_stats":
    {
        "average_rating": 2.325,
        "number_of_ratings": 4
    }
}]
```

I highly encourage you to try it out on **Mongo playground** (after mocking 3 restaurant data documents and 15 reviews): https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pyfqus2w-fl

There are other queries that can be easily acheived with this schema, like getting all the restaurants reviewed by a user, getting the historical or recent reviews of a restaurant (by specifying a certain date range), etc. But for the purpose of this answer I think it's enough. Hope you liked it, please feel free to point out improvements.

Comment: Thank you Anuj Pancholi for this detailed answer.